# python multiprocessing Pool vs Process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Just being noob in this context:

I am try to run one function in multiple processes so I can process a huge file in shorter time

I tried

```
for file_chunk in file_chunks:
    p = Process(target=my_func, args=(file_chunk, my_arg2))
    p.start()
    # without .join(), otherwise main proc has to wait 
    # for proc1 to finish so it can start proc2
```

but it seemed not so really fast enough

now I ask myself, if it is really running the jobs parallelly. I thought about Pool also, but I am using python2 and it is ugly to make it map two arguments to the function.

am I missing something in my code above or the processes that are created this way (like above) run really paralelly?

Comment: How many chunks do you expect to be processed? Are you spinning up hundreds of new processes here? A pool allows you to create a set number of workers and divide the set of chunks (tasks) to the workers without overloading your system.

Comment: @svohara I have 20 chunks only so I can achieve 20 times faster processing which is not happening with this code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The speedup is proportional to the amount of CPU cores your PC has, not the amount of chunks.

Ideally, if you have 4 CPU cores, you should see a 4x speedup. Yet other factors such as IPC overhead must be taken into account when considering the performance improvement.

Spawning too many processes will also negatively affect your performance as they will compete against each other for the CPU.

I'd recommend to use a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) to deal with most of the logic. If you have multiple arguments, just use the `apply_async` method.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool()

for file_chunk in file_chunks:
    pool.apply_async(my_func, args=(file_chunk, arg1, arg2))
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert either, but what you should try is using `joblib` **Parallel**

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed  
import multiprocessing as mp

def random_function(args):
    pass

proc = mp.cpu_count()

Parallel(n_jobs=proc)(delayed(random_function)(args) for args in args_list)
```

This will run a certain function (random_function) using a number of available cpus (n_jobs).

Feel free to read the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html)!